# git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. Error when cloning a repository

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I experience this error whenever I try to clone a repository. The error comes regardless if the repository is private or public. As a result, I cannot clone any repository. The same error comes if I try and create a local repository and publish it to Github.

Github Desktop Version: 1.5.1
OS: Windows 10 64 bit

[Here's a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YC0T.png)

Comment: @IQV: That's how Git internally starts handlers for different URL types.

Comment: @grawity So how do i resolve this error?

Comment: [Same question, with answers, on StackOverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51366101/2662901).